# Show current category related category on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a filter with condition like this.

[image: Category, Related Category]

When I choose Glassware, I want to only show Banana Leaf, Batik, Cili on the filter.
When I choose Dining, I want to only show Classic Round, Curved on the filter.

Glassware related to Banana Leaf because some Glassware product, also belong to Banana Leaf.

Is there any way to get current category related category in WooCommerce.

I saw good example on amara.com https://www.amara.com/shop/pots-pans
The category listed on the filter list will dynamically changing based on category selected.

***Revise:***

Currently my filter look like this.

[image]

All sub category are there.
From image above, actually I just need Arya Panjalu, Cili, Coffee to appear on the filter when I am on Drinkware category.
It is because drinkware only contains products from Arya Panjalu, Cili, Coffee collections.

My code to get the sub category is like this

```
    $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty,
    );
    $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
      echo '<li><input type="checkbox">
              <span>'. $sub_category->name .'</span>
              <span class="filter-count">('.$sub_category->count.')</span>
            </li>';
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

Code above will show all sub category from certain parent category.

Comment: Go to product category edit page change view and from the drop down select sub category